# How to force tree separation size in d3.js?

Tags: d3.js

I have a d3.js graph composed of boxes connected with links.

I want each box to be stacked to the upper one depending on some condition, for instance when the node name starts with a `_`. I used [`tree.separation()`](https://d3js.org/d3-hierarchy/tree#tree_separation) to achieve this.

Here is a proof of concept:

```
<div id="container"></div>
<script type="module">
import * as d3 from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/d3@7/+esm';

const data = { name: 'a', children: [
    { name: 'b' },
    { name: '_c', children: [
        { name: 'd' },
        { name: 'e' },
    ]},
    { name: 'f', children: [
        { name: 'g' },
        { name: 'h' },
    ]},
    { name: '_g' },
]}

const root = d3.hierarchy(data);
const width = 400;
const height = 200;
const box_width = 3;

const svg = d3
    .create('svg')
    .attr('viewBox', [0, 0, 20, 10])
    .style('max-width', `${width}px`)
    .style('font', '1px mono')
    .style('border', 'solid 1px black');

const tree = d3.tree()
    .size([10, 20 - box_width])
    .separation((a, b) => a.data.name[0] === '_' && a.parent === b.parent ? 1 : 2);

tree(root);

const node = svg.append('g')
    .selectAll()
    .data(root.descendants())
    .join('g')
    .attr("transform", (d) => `translate(${d.y},${d.x})`);

        node.append('rect')
            .attr('width', box_width)
            .attr('height', 1)
            .attr('fill', '#ccc')
            .attr('y', -0.5);

        node.append('text')
            .text((d) => d.data.name)
            .attr('y', 0.4);

        svg.append('g') // link
            .attr('fill', 'none')
            .attr('stroke', 'black')
            .attr('stroke-width', 0.1)
            .selectAll()
            .data(root.links())
            .join('path')
    .attr("d", (link) =>
      d3
        .linkHorizontal()
        .x((d) => (d.y == link.source.y ? d.y + box_width : d.y))
        .y((d) => d.x)(link)
    );

container.append(svg.node());
</script>
```

This works well for the data I used in input:

[image]

But if my input is `b`, `c`, `_f` and `g` instead of `b`, `_c`, `f` and `_g` (so the 2 boxes in the center should be stacked), the boxes are not stacked:

[image]

I suppose this is because d3.js wants to avoid having many links close together, but I want to get around this behavior.

Comment: If you get rid of `g` and `h` you will see `_f` come up to join `c`. This maybe implies the algorithm gives priority to child placement. Consider rules 2, 3 and 4 here: https://williamyaoh.com/posts/2023-04-22-drawing-trees-functionally.html#:~:text=In%20Tidier%20Drawings%20of%20Trees,vertical%20level%20in%20the%20output. Good question though... it's no answer to say 'write your own layout algorithm'.